# AlarmManger not working with date

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Hi I am trying to make reminders above api 11.
I did all things with and working on time also means
if i set time , its working but if i want to set reminder for tomorrow or any day
it is not able to do..
so i put this calender code to set alarm which is working.
**With time working**

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // working time only
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    AlarmBcastReceiver alarmBcastReceiver = new AlarmBcastReceiver();
    alarmBcastReceiver.SetAlarm(this, calendar);
```

Now if tried to put date in this calender.
**this is not working i.e.**

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

    // working time only
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    AlarmBcastReceiver alarmBcastReceiver = new AlarmBcastReceiver();
    alarmBcastReceiver.SetAlarm(this, calendar, notiId);
```

I also tried to set this
        //calendar.set(year, month, day, hour, min);
but it also not working.

Comment: What did you set in Month? Did you set using calculation 0-11 or 1-12?

Comment: Here is your "AlarmBcastReceiver" class

Comment: yes yes , every thing is fine , i check in log also.
it is the value after month+1 .

Comment: @VivekAndroid it must be fine. I am asking what are you passing in this? `calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);`?

Comment: it is after month+1 which is perfect showing in log.

Comment: @VivekAndroid Are you passing it using 0 for January, 1 for February, and so on? So for setting alarm for October, you need to pass 9. Did you pass 9 or 10?

Comment: i am passing 10 for October.

Comment: hey its working thanks....have to set 9 for October means setting from 0-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing wrong moth. You are passing 10 and want to test for October. You will need to pass it considering 0-11 for January - December.

Which means,

change your month to 9.

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9);
```

That will make the alarm date of October. So make changes and test.

[A reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14019241/1777090)

Hope this helps.